# Google Cloud TPU support for Tensorflow C++ API

Tags: c++, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

Does Google Cloud TPU support Tensorflow C++ API? I couldn't find any positive or negative statement about that, as well as a sample code or API reference. Does it mean it is not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Tensorflow C++ doesn't have TPU specific API's. 
Tensorflow c++ code should not fail while running on Google Cloud host VM's but it won't be able to use TPU.